# Images on horizontal scroll view according to clicked image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have four images on a `Viewcontroller A` .On the click of those images `Viewcontroller B` having `UIScrollView` presents that has image view and it shows all those four imgaes....Image1 ,image 2,image 3,image 4.
I want that when image 2 is clicked then image 2 appeas as the first image on `Viewcontroller B` ,then image 3,then image 4...Also,when user moves left then it shows previous images including image1 too.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find solution to this problem `Kindly.help`

The code I have used are as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

  width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    _scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:
                 CGRectMake(0,64,width,height)];
      _scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(pageCount*_scroller.bounds.size.width,_scroller.bounds.size.height);
    _scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    _scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
    CGRect ViewSize=_scroller.bounds;

    NSArray *imgArray = [self.tripDetails valueForKey:@"Flightimageurl"];


        for(int i=0;i<[imgArray count];i++)
        {
            UIImageView *imgView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:ViewSize];
            NSString *ImageURL = [imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

            imgView1.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [_scroller addSubview:imgView1];
            [self.view addSubview:_scroller];
            ViewSize =CGRectOffset(ViewSize,_scroller.bounds.size.width,0);

        }


}
```

Comment: Make use of UICollectionView, make UICollectionView cell cover the frame of UICollectionView, set the UICollectionView scroll to horizontal, pass the image array as UICollectionView data source and finally in order to load the image user tapped use collectionView method scrollToItem(at: index) in viewDidLoad set animate property of scrollToItem  to false :)

Comment: Forgot to mention enable paging on UICollectionView :D

Comment: But how will this solve my issue of user clicking image 2 and the first image that loads on Viewcontroller B is image 2 then image 3,image 4?

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code It will be helpful to you**

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

int imageTag = (int) recognizer.view.tag;

NSDictionary *dictCurrentWish = [arrLatestScrollData objectAtIndex:pageNumberSaved];

scrollimagePostView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, kSCREEN_WIDTH, kSCREEN_HEIGHT)];

scrollimagePostView.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrollimagePostView.delegate=self;


UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
[scrollimagePostView addGestureRecognizer:gr];

NSMutableArray *arrTotalImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

[arrTotalImages addObject:[dictCurrentWish objectForKey:@"pic1"]];
[arrTotalImages addObject:[dictCurrentWish objectForKey:@"pic2"]];
[arrTotalImages addObject:[dictCurrentWish objectForKey:@"pic3"]];
[arrTotalImages addObject:[dictCurrentWish objectForKey:@"pic4"]];

int x=0;

CGRect innerScrollFrame = scrollimagePostView.bounds;

for (int i=0; i<arrTotalImages.count; i++) {

    imgViewPost=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 60, kSCREEN_WIDTH,kSCREEN_HEIGHT-90)];


    NSString *strImage  =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrTotalImages objectAtIndex:i]];


    NSString *strURL=[strImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

    NSURL* urlAddress1 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];

    [imgViewPost  sd_setImageWithURL:urlAddress1 placeholderImage:wishPlaceHolderImage];

    imgViewPost.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    imgViewPost.tag = VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG;

    UIScrollView *pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]
                                    initWithFrame:innerScrollFrame];
    pageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    pageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0f;
    pageScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
    pageScrollView.contentSize = imgViewPost.bounds.size;
    pageScrollView.delegate = self;
    pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [pageScrollView addSubview:imgViewPost];
    [scrollimagePostView addSubview:imgViewPost];

    x=x+kSCREEN_WIDTH;

    if (i < 2) {
        innerScrollFrame.origin.x += innerScrollFrame.size.width;
    }

}

scrollimagePostView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollimagePostView.frame.size.height );

scrollimagePostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollimagePostView];


[scrollimagePostView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollimagePostView.frame.size.width*(imageTag-1), 0.0f) animated:NO];


btnCloseFullIMageView = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kSCREEN_WIDTH-80, 25, 70, 25)];
[btnCloseFullIMageView setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCloseFullIMageView setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnCloseFullIMageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
btnCloseFullIMageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
btnCloseFullIMageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
btnCloseFullIMageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
btnCloseFullIMageView.clipsToBounds = TRUE;

[btnCloseFullIMageView addTarget:self action:@selector(closeFullImageView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btnCloseFullIMageView];

}
```